# How to remove duplicate rows based on the first three words of a string in R

Tags: r, string, text

I have a question that I have not been able to find an answer to.

Let's assume that I have the following data frame. The data frame contains the following 3 observations.

```
data.frame (id  = 1:3,
                  sentence = c("Hi my name is John", "Hi my name is Jack", "Hi my name is Drew")
)
```

I want to remove the bottom two observations and just leave the one on the top that has John. A unique() solution does not work given that the last word in each string is different. I am thinking that there should be a way to examine whether the first three (or four) words in each string are the same. If they are the same, then it would delete the other observations except for the one on the top. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to more precisely define what "similar" observations actually means here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen changed the word similar to same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on three words:

```r
gsub("^(\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+).*", "\\1", dat$sentence)
# [1] "Hi my name" "Hi my name" "Hi my name"
dat[!duplicated(gsub("^(\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+).*", "\\1", dat$sentence)),]
#   id           sentence
# 1  1 Hi my name is John
```